# How to integrate Groovy WIth ZK Framework Application?

Tags: groovy, zk

I want to integrate **Groovy** with my **ZK Framework** web application .Any one know how we can integrate Groovy in ZK project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ZK+Groovy Script Integration]  [1](http://zkframeworkhint.blogspot.in/2013/04/how-to-integrate-groovy-with-zk-web.html) As i m using Maven in my ZK Web application ..So i have to made these changes to run **GroovyScript** from my ZK WebApplication..

1. First i have to add this dependency in pom.xml file

> ```
>    <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
>       <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
>       <version>2.1.2</version>
>   </dependency>
> ```

1. Second thing i have to create a Groovy script file and added it into **/src/main/resources** folder.With Following Code.

> def showComponents( ) {
>             myComponentList = [
>                 "Type",
>                 "Status",
>                 "Sub Type",
>                 "Parent ID",
>                 "Work",
>                 "Row ID"
>             ]
>             return myComponentList;
>           }

1. Third and most important thing how to run above created Groovy Script code..as you know the above code returning List of String so we can use below code in my Java class.

   ```
   public List executeGroovyScript(){ 
       List<String> list = null;
       try {
               ClassLoader parent = getClass().getClassLoader();
               GroovyClassLoader loader = new GroovyClassLoader(parent);
               Class groovyClass = loader.parseClass(FileUtils.toFile(
                   this.getClass().getResource("/UserSelectedComponents.groovy")));
               GroovyObject groovyObject = (GroovyObject) groovyClass.newInstance();
               Object[] args = {};
               list = (List)groovyObject.invokeMethod("showComponents", args);

       } catch (Exception ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }
       return list;}
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ZK plugin for Grails which supports Groovy you can read more about it in this [article](http://groovy.dzone.com/articles/implementing-load-demand-using) and download it [here](http://grails.org/plugin/zk)

Comment: I saw this link but its a Grail project while i have ZK project and now i want to add Groovy on that

Comment: read the docs on it I'm sure you can. I haven't done it myself so I'm afraid I can't offer more guidance.